# MongoDB how to filter by two fields(id and month) and also return a sum by all the filtered documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hi I am working on writing a Node/Express endpoint and I am trying to write a MongoDB query using Mongoose to return a sum value of my documents that have an expiration within the current day or month.

Currently, I am just trying to return the sum for the current day.

- First I want to match all documents that contains the user's id.
- Then I want to match all documents within the current day.
- Lastly, I want to return the sum of the `$amount` field for all those
  documents.

I know that the syntax for this is wrong and I am having a hard time find good examples matching what I am doing.

```
let now = Date.now(),
    oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    today = new Date(now - (now % oneDay)),
    tomorrow = new Date(today.valueOf() + oneDay);

router.get("/user_current_month/:id", [jsonParser, jwtAuth], (req, res) => {
    return Expense.aggregate([
        {
            $match: { user: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                $expiration: {
                    $gte: today,
                    $lt: tomorrow
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$month",
                total: {
                    $sum: "$amount"
                }
            }
        }
    ])
        .then(sum => {
            res.status(200).json(sum);
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went terribly wrong!" }));
});
```

This is what a document looks like:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5daea018b3d92643fc2c8e6c"
    },
    "user": {
        "$oid": "5d9929f065ef083d2cdbf66c"
    },
    "expense": "Post 1",
    "expenseType": "One Time",
    "notes": "",
    "amount": {
        "$numberDecimal": "100"
    },
    "expiration": {
        "$date": "2019-10-22T06:22:01.628Z"
    },
    "status": "Active",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2019-10-22T06:22:16.644Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the two match expressions in a AND clause and then group to perform the addition operation. You need to do something like this:

```
Expense.aggregate([
    { $match: { $and: [{ user: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) },
   {
                $expiration: {
                    $gte: today,
                    $lt: tomorrow
                }
            } ]}},
    { $group: {
            _id: "$month",
            total: {
                $sum: "$amount"
            }
        }}
    ]);
```

Comment: I am getting `MongoError: unknown top level operator: $expiration` when running a callback function to log the result. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind I got it, removed the $ on expiration. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the typo there!